# Tilemaps - When overriding StartUp, what does returning base.StartUp do?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a situation where I am instantiating a prefab based on a variable in StartUp

```
public override bool StartUp(Vector3Int position, ITilemap iTilemap, GameObject go)
    {
        if (isSingularTile)
        {
            GameObject clone1 = Instantiate(prefab, go.transform);
            clone1.transform.position = new Vector3(position.x, position.y, position.z);
            return base.StartUp(position, iTilemap, go);
        }
        return base.StartUp(position, iTilemap, go);
    }
```

Does the line `return.StartUp(position, iTilemap, go);` do anything in particular, or might I just as well return true?

Comment: It depends on what base.StartUp does.  Calling the base will execute the base method on the base type.  Without seeing what the method you are overriding does, it is impossible to know if you should call it or not.

Comment: The Unity documentation does not say anything about what base.StartUp does. I was hoping someone might have experimented and found something out though.

Comment: what class are you inheriting?

Comment: The Tile class. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tile.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code for [TileBase](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Modules/Tilemap/Managed/TileBase.cs)

```
[RequiredByNativeCode]
public virtual bool StartUp(Vector3Int position, ITilemap tilemap, GameObject go) { return false; }
```

It seems the default implementation returns false.  The Tile class which implements TileBase does not override StartUp and thus does not change the default return value from false.

According to the manual, the return value indicates if the call was successful.

```
Returns
bool Whether the call was successful.
```

I believe you should return true when your code runs successfully (all objects are spawned and no exceptions thrown) and false if something went wrong to the point that the tile cannot be recovered.  Though I am not sure where that return value is being used.

For now I would just return true and forget about it. (or if that doesnt work return the base.StartUp(..))

```
public override bool StartUp(Vector3Int position, ITilemap iTilemap, GameObject go)
{
    if (isSingularTile)
    {
        GameObject clone1 = Instantiate(prefab, go.transform);
        clone1.transform.position = new Vector3(position.x, position.y, position.z);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is a link to the [Managed Tilemaps](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/tree/master/Modules/Tilemap/Managed) source code if you want to dig further.

Comment: That's a really good answer! Thanks. I didn't know about the source code... but the source code also seems to be kind of incomplete...? How does that work. Is that source code the actual source code?

Comment: That is the actual source code, these particular links are for version 2020.2.0a13.  It is really nice that they made their source code public.  I cannot vouch for completeness, though I would be surprised if it was incomplete.